# YouTube iFrame API for Loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I want to create loop for youtube iframe API, what I am trying is

```
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

var vidslide1, vidslide2, vidslide3;

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        for(var i = 0; i < vidslide.length;i++) {
          vidslide[i] = new YT.Player(vidslide[i], {
            events: {
              'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
            }
          }); 
          }
   }
```

But its not working. I am trying to create 3 iframes in slider.

Here is my html.

```
<?php $count = 0; ?>           
<?php foreach($sliders->results() as $slider): $count++; ?>

<div class="item">
<iframe id="vidslide<?php echo $count; ?>" class="embed-responsive-item" width="75%" height="500" src="<?php _lang($slider['url'])?>?enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>           
</div>

<?php endforeach ?>
```

Anyone can help?

Comment: Can you add any details like: error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Comment: I don't know, it simply not working and breaking slider cycle. I am still a learner.